# About the the stability of using an explicit scheme on the heat equation

Tags: finite-difference, stability

Before I get to the heat equation I'd like to talk about the advection equation.
Descritize that with FD in time and BD in space:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{u^{n+1}_i - u^{n}_i}{\Delta t} + v \dfrac{u^{n}_{i} - u^{n}_{i-1}}{\Delta x}= 0
\end{equation}
there are higher order terms which were cancelled out so let's bring those back in ie. trucnation errors:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\Delta t}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}  + v \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} -v\dfrac{\Delta x}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0
\end{equation}
Move things around a lil:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}   + v \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = -v\dfrac{\Delta x}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\Delta t}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}
\end{equation}
with some vodo magic
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}   + v \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = -v\dfrac{\Delta x}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + v^2\dfrac{\Delta t}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x} 
\end{equation}
and some compression
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}   + v \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = \dfrac{v}{2} \left(- \Delta x + v \Delta t    \right)\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x} + \text{higher order terms}
\end{equation}
When the convection equation is discretized we don't solve the original equation but the equation written above. If the RHS coefficient  $-\Delta x + v \Delta t$

- Positive $-\Delta x + v \Delta t > 0 \implies \dfrac{v \Delta x}{\Delta t}<1$ we get the CFL condition and a positive diffusion coefficient which is why explicit schemes are explicit. A low CFL would imply more diffusion.
- negative $-\Delta x + v \Delta t > 0$ implies a negative coefficient for second order derivative which is why the solution blows up.

Now I am trying to apply this rational to the heat equation. Descritize that with FD in time and CD in space:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{u^{n+1}_i - u^{n}_i}{\Delta t} = D  \dfrac{u^{n}_{i+1} -2  u^{n}_{i} + u^{n}_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2}
\end{equation}
the truncated equation:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\Delta t}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}  = D \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +  D \dfrac{\Delta x^2}{12}\dfrac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^2} 
\end{equation}
and finally
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}  = D \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} -D^2 \dfrac{\Delta t}{2}\dfrac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4} +  D \dfrac{\Delta x^2}{12}\dfrac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4}
 \end{equation}
compress a lil:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}  = D \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} 
+\left (-D^2 \dfrac{\Delta t}{2} +  D \dfrac{\Delta x^2}{12} \right)
   \dfrac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4}
 \end{equation}
I wouldn't want a negative coefficient next to the fourth order derivative because that would mean that I would be solving an equation that blows up (I guess) so I want to guarantee that:

- $-D^2 \dfrac{\Delta t}{2} +  D \dfrac{\Delta x^2}{12} > 0 \implies \dfrac{D \Delta t }{\Delta x^2}< \dfrac{1}{6} $
  which is not consistent with the Von Neumann stability condition for this scheme which is:
- $\dfrac{D \Delta t }{\Delta x^2}< \dfrac{1}{2} $

**any hints where I went wrong?**

Comment: For a Fourier mode exp(ikx -iwt), the second derivative produces $(ik)^2=-k^2$, so for the mode growth rate to be negative we want $D (-k^2)$ to be negative, that's why we need positive diffusion coefficient D. For hyper-diffusion (the 4th derivative operator) it would be $D_4 k^4$, so the coefficient $D_4$ in front should be negative. But your equation has both 2nd and 4th derivative on RHS, so the proper analysis should be done by putting a Fourier mode there and combining all terms to make the mode growth rate negative, that should be easy to do.

Comment: Looks like I missed the diffusion part. I still would like to do this without resorting to fourier analysis and stick to truncation error analysis

Comment: But note that for the 4th derivative term the condition of not blowing up should have sign opposite to what you have there, based on those Fourier analysis arguments.

Comment: Did you figure this out finally? I am also interested in a similar problem.

Comment: I am confused about what is the differential equation that you want to analyze.

Comment: @nicoguaro : As stated in the title, the final problem is about the heat equation $\frac{∂u}{∂t}=D\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, yes, now I get it. I was confused by the motivation with the advection equation.

Comment: @CFDIAC Nah. I slept on that